# Multiple switches on a linked system of strip lights

Tags: lighting

Is it possible to link 4 strip lights together, with only one cord plugged into a wall, and then install what I think are called in-line switches between each strip light, and be able to turn each light on or off as needed? It seemed impossible when I thought about it, but I don't completely understand how electricity works, so I thought I'd ask here. Since two of the three wires are not affected by an inline switch, I thought that may cause it to be possible to do what I want to do, but I don't want to spend $160 or so on the lights and switches and cord link connectors without knowing if this would work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Home Improvement! The answer is "yes, if you can find the right products." Unfortunately, "shopping" questions are off-topic. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how better to contribute here.

Comment: What do you mean by strip lights? 4' LED shop lights? With more specifics we may be able to help.